# Consequences of log equivalence

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose $1<x_n\longrightarrow\infty$ is such that $\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}x_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=\rho>1$. What can we say about the growth of $x_n$, besides that $\log x_n \sim n\log \rho$? I was interested mainly in figuring out if there is anything to say, that speaks more directly about the slowest possible growth of $x_n$ without logarithms involved.

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that $\limsup x_n/\rho^n > 0$; for example, take $x_n = \rho^n / n$.

Comment: Thank you you are right, gotta double check what I wrote, probably some careless mistakes hides somewhere. I remove that statement.

Comment: Fixed the mistake, what I actually get, also picking up from your hint, is that at the worst, if $x_n=o(\rho^n)$, rewriting $x_n=\rho^n\epsilon_n$ for $\epsilon_n\longrightarrow 0$, one has that $\log\varepsilon_n=o(n)$, which allows all sorts of polynomial dumping $\epsilon_n=1/n^k$ for any $k$...

Comment: The polynomial dumping is definitely correct; however the claims about $\epsilon_n$ are a little too broad (take $x_n = \rho^{n/2}$ or even $x_n=1$ for example).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I was only interested in the slowest possible regimes, I'll add it. I do not think $_=^{n/2}$ would do as the limit of $x_n^{1/n}$ would be $\sqrt{\rho}$ and not $\rho$. Same with $_=1$ which would have limit 1 but $\rho>1$.